# Show that if $h$ is holomorphic on $D$ then $h$ is neverzero in $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis

How can I deal with this problem?

Let $D=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\right\}$, $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a nonconstant $C^{1}$ function, and $g:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a neverzero function such that both $\Re g$ and $\Im g$ are $C^{1}$. Let $h$ be the product of $f$ and $g$. Show that if $h$ is a holomorphic function on $D$ then $f$ is neverzero in $D$.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The title is not the same as the question. The function $f$ being nonzero in $D$ means that $f$ is not identically zero in $D$, which is trivial since $f$ is non-constant. Do you mean that $f$ is nowhere zero in $D$? How about $g$?

Comment: @user218931 The question is probably asking to show that $f$ is never zero.

Comment: You're right! Never zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a question of continuity (and not $C^1$). Suppose $h$ has a zero of order $n$ at, say $z=0$. Then with $z=r e^{i\phi}$:
  $$f(z)= \frac{h(z)}{g(z)} =  C z^n \frac{1+O(z)}{g(0)+\epsilon(z)}=  e^{in\phi} \frac{C r^n}{g(0)}  (1+ \epsilon(z))$$
It follows that 
$$ \frac{f(z)}{|f(z)|} = e^{in\phi} e^{i \alpha} \frac{1+\epsilon(z)}{|1+\epsilon(z)|}$$
can not be purely real-valued for $r$ small, contrary to the hypothesis on $f$.

Comment: Sorry, what is $\epsilon(z)$?

Comment: a complex valued function that goes to zero as $z\rightarrow 0$. In the present context you could write $O(z)$. I was just emphasizing that the result is valid even if we only assume continuity of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.